# Why the process is not blocked for read/write from pipe system call

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am study the `pipe` system call and create a simple code snippet to play with it.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    int ffd[2], sfd[2];
    if (pipe(ffd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(sfd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int n = 10, rc;
    rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (rc == 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("child - %ld\n", i);
            read(ffd[0], NULL, 0);
            write(sfd[1], NULL, 0);
        }
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("parent - %ld\n", i);
            write(ffd[1], NULL, 0);
            read(sfd[0], NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
parent - 0
child - 0
parent - 1
child - 1
parent - 2
child - 2
parent - 3
child - 3
parent - 4
child - 4
parent - 5
child - 5
parent - 6
child - 6
parent - 7
child - 7
parent - 8
child - 8
parent - 9
child - 9
```

Since after parent write to `ffd[0]`, it will try to read from `sfd[1]`, however there is no data available yet, what I learned is the parent process will block waiting for data and OS will switch to execute child process. Similar thing happens for child process, so the output should be intertwined.
But when I run the code I got output as

```
parent - 0
parent - 1
parent - 2
parent - 3
parent - 4
parent - 5
parent - 6
parent - 7
parent - 8
parent - 9
child - 0
child - 1
child - 2
child - 3
child - 4
child - 5
child - 6
child - 7
child - 8
child - 9
```

I was wondering why the result is like this. Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to write and read 0 bytes of data. Why should that block? You should be checking the return values from `read()` and `write()`...

Comment: What does [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) say about the behavior of a 0-length read?

Comment: What [the man page for `write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) says about it ought to raise a red flag.